# Why is the loop not being vectorized?

Tags: c++, optimization, vector, vectorization

I know that vectorization can only take place if the objects being accessed are contiguous in memory. I have created a struct which has pointer and then I create a vector of this struct and to ensure that the pointers inside the vector of objects are pointing to contiguous data blocks I set them to point to elements in a vector of double with the same size.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Vec {
   Vec() {}
   double* a;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   std::vector<double> vec_double(10000000, 1.0);
   std::vector<Vec> vec_vec(10000000);
   for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
      vec_vec[i].a = &(vec_double[i]);

   // Why is this loop not vectorized
   for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
      vec_double[i] += *(vec_vec[i].a);

   double sum = 0.0;
   for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i)
      sum += vec_double[i];
   std::cout << sum << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

However, even with O3 optimization the loop at line number 16 is not getting vectorized. Can someone please explain why is this happening?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guessing here, but when just looking at this specific loop, the compiler does not know that `vec_vec[i].a` points to the memory location next to `vec_vec[i+1].a`. Therefore, it cannot do the calculation without dereferencing each `.a` member separately.

It could know that, when looking at the loop above. But if it would do that, it could also look at the loop below, calculate the final result and print it.

Comment: In other words, compiler does not vectorize indirection (by pointers).

Answer (score 0):

You should get the raw pointer from the iterator first. Like this `vec_vec.begin()_Ptr` and `vec_double.begin()._Ptr`. Work with those pointers like in legacy. And finaly declare method that it does no aliasing. Like this `__declspec(noalias)`. And it should do the trick on windows with msvc. I don`t think there is a noalias attribute on GCC though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not true that "vectorization can only take place if the objects being accessed are contiguous in memory". It's **quite possible to vectorize loops with non-contiguous memory accesses**, and it's even hardware-level supported  on newer CPUs like Haswell, where you have v(p)gather* instructions supporting "random memory access pattern" codes vectorization.

However, secondly, vectorizing codes with non-contiguous access is often very **inefficient**. Contiguous (also called "unit-stride" in this context) memory access is mostly always prefferable to have in vector code (although contiguous access patterns could be worse from memory bandwidth perspective, but it's separate long topic). So your optimization technique was appropriate.

Now, third, access pattern is just one of tens and hundreds of **other reasons** why compiler didn't vectorize the loop automatically or even didn't vectorize it after nudging it using some pragmas/etc.
In your given case, there could be 2 reasons why gcc was confused by given code:

1. Pointers. Compiler can't safely assume what is an actual value of pointer in runtime and has to assume worse (let's say p[i] and p[i+1] point to the same or even conflicting memory locations, and as a result overwrite each other or do something worse).
2. Just code complexity. In some cases, dealing with object oriented codes, also involving STL, etc, makes vectorizers confused.

Both issues are usually well solvable using restrict keyword (not your case I guess), #pragma ivdep or #pragma omp simd.
The thing is however, that pragmas ivdep and simd are only "reliably" supported starting from GCC version 4.**9**.

One another way is to rewrite your code so that it doesn't deal with pointers and maybe even vectors, but just use some C style array of fixed size. Of course it's terrible recommendations for real C++ codes, but in your given code snippet it's doable, since you statically specify array size.

Comment: I get your point about using array with specific sizes but I am actually using this in a C++ library that I am developing so it has to work with dynamically alloacted objects. Coming to your point 1 when you say that p[i] and p[i+1] can point to the same memory locations shouldn't I be able to overcome that problem by telling the compiler to use -fno-strict-aliasing ?

Comment: My point was about situation when pointers (possibly corresponding to the *same* data type) may refer to overlapping (or "statically unpredictable") regions in theory, while in practice they naturally don't. -fno-strict-aliasing is about pointers to "two objects of *different* types". So, for your case I'd still suggest upgrading to gcc4.9 or possibly using restrict keyword.